npm run start - Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/.../node_modules/next/next-swc-fallback'
With IntelliJ, I create a configuration to run my front-end app.
I got the back, working with Docker, and the front also work with it.
So when I run my front with the config I create (like a npm run start), I got this error :
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/8f0fa976-ef9b-4a64-ad5d-e3e7349dfbe9/node_modules/next/next-swc-fallback'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/tmp/8f0fa976-ef9b-4a64-ad5d-e3e7349dfbe9/node_modules/next/next-swc-fallback'
}

The container is created in my Docker Dashboard, he stays active, but the console exit and stop the process.
Don't know what to do.

change ownership of the current working directory to the user the app using in dockerfile.

@MohammedEhab but it's actually me for both
